# Unsure what model to create

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to build a set of survey forms (public) and each of those should have a review form (behind login) to say some useful things about each submission.

I've been able to tie some stuff together, but I feel like I'm having way too many classes (one for each survey form, one for each review form). Not exactly DRY, so my architecture is all wrong. Anyone who can steer me in the right direction of what my models should look like?

Comment: Do all reviews look similar? If so why not just use one model for review?

Comment: Unfortunately the review forms are different (and have to be because of very different surveys contents). One of the reasons I'm stuck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is build an abstract model from which all review models inherit.

Or if they just have different logic you could create proxy models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/

As for tying stuff together you should really look at formsets. They help turn 2 or more models into what effectively acts like 1 form. So you could have 1 survey form type tied to N number of review form types. That being said, this is not beginner stuff. You should go through the Django tutorial project. Once you have a STRONG understanding of it take a look a 2 scoops of django.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm on the path you suggested and this is already proving useful.